# Upgrade version of scikit-learn included in Enthought Canopy distribution

Tags: python, scikit-learn, enthought, canopy, pythonpath

I have EPD 7.3.1 installed (nowadays called Enthought Canopy), which comes with scikit-learn v 0.11. I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I need to install v 0.12 of scikit-learn.

The scikit-learn [doc says](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/index.html#git-repo) clone the repository, add the scikit-learn directory to your PYTHONPATH, and build the extension in place: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

The problem is that EPD is its own closed world (with mulitple scikit dirs):
`./lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikits/`
`./lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn`

And then there's:
`./EGG-INFO/scikit_learn/`

I really don't want to experiment as it has taken a very long time to get things tuned to this point. Should I follow scikit-learn's directions in this case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The actions described on the scikit-learn website work irrespective of the scikit-learn version in EPD. Python will automatically use the scikit-learn version set in the `PYTHONPATH` [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), which you should set to the directory path of the Git version of scikit-learn.

If you use Bash on a Unix-like system, you should do the following:

- Perform the actions to [install scikit-learn's latest code](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/index.html#retrieving-the-latest-code) (in this example I cloned it to `/home/yourname/bin/scikit-learn`)
- Edit `.bashrc` and add the line: `export PYTHONPATH="/home/yourname/bin/scikit-learn";`
- Open a new terminal and start Python in interactive mode by typing `python`

  - Type: `import sklearn`
  - Type: `sklearn.__verion__` this should now show `'0.12-git'` instead of `0.11`

Why does this work? Python uses the variable `sys.path` (a `list` of paths) internally to keeps track of all the directories where it should look for modules and packages. Once a module or package is requested, Python will sequentially go through this list until it has found a match. So, e.g., a module can be listed multiple times in `sys.path`, but only the version which appeared first in the list will be used.

Every Python installation will have its own default set of paths listed in `sys.path`. One way of extending `sys.path` is by listing paths in `PYTHONPATH`. Once Python starts it will read this environment variable and add it to the start of the `sys.path` list. So if you add the path to another version of scikit-learn to your `PYTHONPATH` then (EPD's) Python will find that version of scikit-learn first and use it instead of the version listed further on in `sys.path`.

To view `sys.path`, simply `import sys` and then `print sys.path`. Also, e.g., if you only want to use the 0.12 version of scikit-learn in one Python program and use the 0.11 version as default in all other Python programs then you could leave the `PYTHONPATH` empty and only insert the path to scikit-learn 0.12 manually at the top of your code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/yourname/bin/scikit-learn')
import sklearn
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow the community gives downvotes to bad questions and upvotes to good questions. I would leave the question for now, but if people start to downvote it then you have a good indication that you might want to delete it.

Comment: I've run into the same problem, but I have a Mac. I've managed to install scikit only via macports (not using scikits setup.py, always ends in error mid-way). However, I can't find the bashrc. All I want to do is update Scikit in EPD(academic) to .13, and it's proving very difficult, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Shinjitsu Try using .profile instead of .bashrc. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @plurker oddly spotlight is unable to find either .profile or .bashrc. However, I was able to finally get it to work! However, it's been a while since I did it. I believe I uninstalled the package from the enthought distribution and then i installed it using the "install" command in the terminal using files provided in the zip file.